# Automatically Run as Admin on Windows Startup

Tags: c#, autostart, elevated-privileges

I put this code to make my wpf app run automatically on windows startup:

```
 Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
```

I created an msi through InstallShield and installed my wpf and launch it then I restarted my machine and it runs automatically on next startup.

The problem is when I create a new app.manifest file and add the following code to make my app run as admin:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
```

and remove this line of code:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

It does not run anymore on next startup.

What did I miss in the process?

Comment: What does the event log say in event viewer

Comment: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user EFREN-PC\Efren SID (S-1-5-21-3973397334-3483704011-1788101054-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: As far as i know, there is only one way to run an application on start-up with administrator execution level. And that is using Windows Scheduler.

Comment: So the msi that I'm going to make has to automatically create a scheduled task? Or that is not possible, the user must manually create a scheduled task?

Comment: It should be possible, since each anti-virus programs does this. Perhaps there is some other way _(not using Scheduler at all)_. I researched this a few years ago only for my personal use on my computer, therefore the manual one time operation using Scheduler was sufficient for me. I set the 'On log-on' start-up and requested start-up mode _(administrator)_. But when you your need to make an installer, this is not the best way... _(manual use of Scheduler)_